# How can a discrete stochastic integral be used to show that $(X_n)$ submartingale, $S\le T\implies E(X_S)\le E(X_T)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am just learning about martingales and discrete stochastic integrals. For completeness, we define a discrete stochastic integral as
$$Y_n=\sum_{k=1}^nC_k(X_k-X_{k-1})=(C\bullet X)_n$$
for $(X_n)$ adapted and $C_n$ previsible in this context.

An exercise from this section says we can use a discrete stochastic integral to show that if $(X_n)$ is submartingale and $S, T$ are a.s. bounded stopping times with $S\le T$ then $E(X_S)\le E(X_T)$.

Because of the boundedness of the stopping times, I thought this looked more like an optional stopping problem, but the exercise clearly states that this can be shown using a suitable discrete stochastic integral.

Does someone know how the stochastic integral relates to this problem?

EDIT: The only result I already have for the discrete stochastic integral is
if $C_n\ge 0$ then $(C\bullet X)_n$ is a submartingale as well. Perhaps I need to define a discrete stochastic integral and then apply optional stopping to that?

Comment: You are working completely in the discrete setting, right? Just to clarify.

Comment: Also, can you mention the results about the discrete stochastic integral that are mentioned in the chapter you are reading from? Elsewise mention the book and which chapter you are reading from, and what results you know about the discrete stochastic integral.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, discrete. I have added what I know (which isn't much).

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I will attempt an answer, and your intuition is right, on first glance.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon no luck?

Comment: **Suggestion:** The stochastic integral with integrand $C^S_k=1_{\{k\le S\}}$ (keep adding $X_k-X_{k-1}$ so long as $k\le S$) has value $X_{S\wedge n}-X_0$ at time $n$. Likewise for $T$. 

Two questions: (i) How are $C^S_k$ and $C^T_k$ related? (ii) Under what conditions is the stochastic integral a submartingale when $X$ is a submartingale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result for the discrete stochastic integral that you mention, is exactly what is required. Furthermore the required stochastic integral is also easy to construct.

Let's take two a.s. bounded stopping times $S \leq T$. There is an implicit filtration w.r.t which $X_n$ is adapted and a submartingale, that I call as $\mathcal F_n$.

First, note that $X_S$ and $X_T$ are well-defined random variables, because $S$ and $T$ are stopping times. Since $T$ is a.s. bounded there is a natural number $M>0$ such that $T \leq M$ a.s. and because of this, we know that $|X_T|= \sum_{i=0}^M 1_{\{T = i\}} |X_i|$ a.s. , but the RHS is integrable by linearity and has integral at most equal to $ME[|X_0|] < \infty$ since $X_0$ is part of a submartingale hence is by definition integrable. Therefore, $E[|X_T|]< \infty$ and so $E[X_T] < \infty$.

In a similar fashion, $E[X_S] < \infty$.

Now, like the optional stopping theorem, we introduce a $t_0 > 0$, and wish to prove $E[X_{T \wedge t_0}] \geq E[X_{S \wedge t_0}]$ before taking $t_0 \to \infty$ and ensuring things work out.

To do this, we prove that $X_{T \wedge t_0} - X_{S \wedge t_0}$ equals a discrete stochastic integral of $X_n$ by a non-negative random variable. Hence it will be a sub-martingale, and we can use the optional stopping theorem.

But such a sub-martingale is easy to create : let $C_n = 1_{T \geq n} - 1_{S \geq n}$. Then note that $\sum_{i=1}^{t_0} C_i (X_{i}-X_{i-1}) = X_{T \wedge t_0} - X_{S \wedge T_0}$ by an easy $\omega$-by-$\omega$ check. $C_n$ is non-negative a.s. since $S \leq T$, and $C_n$ is *previsible* since each of $T \geq n$ and $S \geq n$ are $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ measurable, and $C_n$ is just a linear combination of their indicators.

Therefore, the conclusion is that $Y_{t_0} = X_{T \wedge t_0} - X_{S \wedge t_0}$ is a well defined submartingale, with $Y_0 = 0$. But then, for a submartingale it is well known that the sequence $E[Y_n]$ is an increasing sequence. Therefore $E[Y_0] \leq E[Y_n]$, which gives us that $E[X_{T \wedge t_0}]  \geq E[X_{S \wedge t_0}]$ for all $t_0$.

Finally, note that as $t_0 \to \infty$, the a.s. boundedness of $T$ and $S$ imply that for $t_0 >M$ we have $T \wedge t_0 = T$ and $S \wedge t_0 = S$ a.s. , so the pointwise limits $X_{T \wedge t} \to X_T$ and $X_{S \wedge t} \to X_S$ hold a.s.

It is now about the dominated convergence theorem, but then that is clear since $|X_{T \wedge t}| \leq \sum_{i=0}^M 1_{\{T=i\}} |X_i|$ a.s. , and the latter has finite expectation. Similarly for $S$. Now we conclude that $E[X_T] \geq E[X_S]$.

---

In continuous time, more regularity must be imposed on both the filtration and the process itself if we are to obtain a result of the kind above. But it does hold.

Comment: Thank you! As a comment, the discrete stochastic integral generalizes to the continuous stochastic integral, which is more difficult to define in generality and is therefore seen first for the Brownian motion, followed by an extension to so called semimartingales. The notion of stochastic integration is very useful for a result of the kind you mention, because just like here, where we express a quantity as a stochastic integral and take advantage of a known theorem, there too it is possible to do the same, and results are comparison theorems for solutions of SDEs and time adjusted BMs.

Comment: This is a nice answer! I also wanted to mention that the discrete stochastic integral of a process is also known as the Doob transform of a process and the $H$-transform of a process (the variable $H$ is frequently used analogously to $C$ in this answer).

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Thanks for the additional information! I will keep this in mind when I write answers in the future.